# Trying to Login But Whenever i tried to login it run catch condition and display failed

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to Login a user using this code that I defined in a class. Whenever I tried to login it runs catch condition and display failed as you can see in the code. Please help me to solve this problem

Here is the Class code:

```
public bool Select(hostelClass h)
    {
        bool isSuccess = false;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconnstring);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            string sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hm_login WHERE username=@username AND password=@password";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", h.username);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", h.password);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            conn.Open();
            var i = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                UserID = h.username;
                welcome settingsForm = new welcome();
                settingsForm.Show();
                isSuccess = true;
            }
            else
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Please enter Correct Username or Password");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed");
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return isSuccess;
    }
```

Here is the Form/Button Code

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hc.username = textBoxUsername.Text;
    hc.password = textBoxPassword.Text;
              
    bool value = hc.Select(hc);
    
    if (value)
    {
         clear();
         this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally we need to know what the error (exception) is, in order to help you.  But you are calling 'ExecuteNonQuery', but it is a select statement, so this is not valid (you need ExecuteQuery).

Comment: You should also declare both Connection and Command with `using` statements; the DataAdapter is not needed at all here, you can simply use the `DataTable.Load([DataReader])` method. -- It's not clear what becomes of your DataTable, nobody is using it anywhere after it's filled. + What is that `UserID`, which is parachuted into a method from nowhere, what the role of the `hostelClass` object is and where it's declared etc. -- A lot of stuff to redesign here.

Answer (score -1):

Several things to change in your approach.
Instead of "select *", you can query as "Select 1 from..".
Use the `command.Parameters.Add()`, instead of `AddwithValue()`.  AddwithValue is known to have [issues](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).
Call the `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` instead of ExecuteNonQuery.

Comment: This is not working

Comment: Update your question with latest code that you are trying, and the exact error details.

Comment: try
            {
                string sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hm_login WHERE username=@username AND password=@password";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", h.username);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", h.password);

Comment: My Question Limit is exceeded

Comment: SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                conn.Open();
                var i = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                adapter.Fill(dt);

Comment: code is updated kidnly check

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.Varchar); cmd.Parameters["@password"].Value = h.password;`

Comment: Similarly fill the parameter value for username. And let us know the result of calling ExecuteScalar()